# Tutorial for Google Wallet and CSP

Tags: android-pay

With CSP required by Google Chrome Apps, is there any official guidance from Google about the domains that should be added to the CSP for a Chrome App?

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

What seemed to work for me

script-src 'self' https://checkout.google.com https://www.google.com